# How to exclude vuetify and vue from the build?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I create a custom library through VueCLI. I would like to reduce the size of the build by not including vuetify and vue.js in the final bundle.

My final build file (*.umd.min.js) works correctly when building with command:

`vue-cli-service build --inline-vue --target lib --formats umd-min ./src/components/Component.vue`

If I externalize vuetify and vue.js, then when I connect the library I get error:

`Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined` in the vuetify library

How to remove vuetify and vue.js from the build?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      symlinks: false,
      alias: {
        vue$: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js')
      }
    }
  },
```

in your vue.config.js of the App using the library.

Answer (score 0):

I use build command:
`vue-cli-service build --target lib --formats umd-min ./src/components/Component.vue`

And registered vuetify components globally in core app.

Comment: Didn't make any difference in file size for me regarding vuetify.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using roll up as described in the guide here.

https://blog.harveydelaney.com/creating-your-own-vue-component-library/

The key is to make sure vuetify is listed in peerDependencies in your package.json.

Comment: peerDependencies makes no differences in the output, but why?

Comment: I am uncertain about your question. But yes the peerDeps will only be used during the build process and not bundled in the final output. Since you would not want every vue component to be included in your distribution.

Comment: I mean putting vuetify to dependencies or to peerDependencies makes no difference in th e build output - I was expecting the output to become smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I can avoid this error with following settings of **babel.config.js**.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

I've got a library which doesn't include vue nor vuetify because use them as external objects:

[image]

For more detail, refer this [repository](https://github.com/UedaTakeyuki/qrcode-of-this-site2).